# LaTeX3: \dim_set:Nn with l3calc or calc type dimension expression

Tags: latex3, dimension-expressions

I am getting an error when I try to set a dimension register with a l3calc/calc type dimension expression using LaTeX3 `\dim_set:Nn` command. Even wrapping the whole expression into `\dim_eval:n{}` doesn't help. What can I do?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{l3calc}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\mydim}

\setlength\mydim{15pt*\ratio{5pt}{10pt}} %this works
\typeout{\the\mydim} %7.5pt

\ExplSyntaxOn
\dim_set:Nn\mydim{15pt*\ratio{5pt}{10pt}} %error
\dim_set:Nn\mydim{\dim_eval:n{15pt*\ratio{5pt}{10pt}}} %same error
\ExplSyntaxOff

\typeout{\the\mydim} %don't get here

\end{document}
```

Comment: For later readers.  As of July 2012, LaTeX3 provides an expandable floating point unit, so all those computations can be done (albeit more slowly than in dimension expressions) with a natural syntax: `\fp_set:Nn \myfp { 15pt * 5pt / (10pt) }`, or to get a dimension, `\dim_set:Nn \mydim { \fp_to_dim:n { 15pt * 5pt / (10pt) } }`.  The parenthesis may or may not be needed depending on the precise revision of our code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dim_set` uses e-TeX syntax, not `calc` syntax. Either use the functions from the `l3calc` module (`calc_dim_set` etc.), or convert your expression to e-TeX syntax:

```
\calc_dim_set:Nn\mydim{15pt*\ratio{5pt}{10pt}}
\dim_set:Nn\mydim{5pt*15/10}
```

Comment: I think that a simple ratio function is probably desirable. Also note that we've taken `l3calc` out of the main `expl3` code block as there are some issues with the implementation and with the overlap with e-TeX.

Comment: @Joseph: Will `l3calc` become deprecated eventually?

Comment: @Alexander: It already is, in the sense that `expl3` no longer loads it. (`l3calc` is an early try-out for the LaTeX3 approach, and as I said there are bits which no longer make sense.)

Comment: Also note that `expl3` deliberately loads `calc` to avoid issues if people are expecting `l3calc` to be loaded.

Answer (score 3):

The way that `calc` works is that it patches `\setlength` to do a lot of scanning in order to work. As a result, if you look at the definition of `\ratio` *outside* of `\setlength` it is just `\relax`. On the other hand, `\dim_set:Nn` is much more akin to directly setting a TeX dimen register: the definition is (in primitives)

```
\protected \def \dim_set:Nn #1#2 { #1 \dimexpr #2 \relax }
```

while  `\dim_eval:n` is

```
\def \dim_eval:n #1 { \the \dimexpr #1 \relax }
```

So when you try to do

```
\dim_set:Nn \mydim { 20pt * \ratio { 5pt } { 10pt } }
```

`\ratio` is `\relax`, and you get an error as the dimension expression ends early.

Now, on what to do, I guess that this is going to need a little though from the LaTeX3 team. We've recently moved `l3calc` out of `expl3` as some of it is no longer that useful, but we know that bits certainly are.  What I guess we need here is an expandable `\dim_ratio:nn` function to return the ratio between two dimension expressions. I'll schedule that for addition to `expl3`: probably there won't be a CTAN release until after the TeX Live 2011 freeze, but I'll post the code as an edit here once it's done.

---

I now have some code for an expandable ratio function which can therefore be used inside `\dim_set:Nn`:

```
\cs_new_nopar:Npn \dim_ratio:nn #1#2
  { \dim_ratio_aux:n {#1} / \dim_ratio_aux:n {#2} }
\cs_new_nopar:Npn\dim_ratio_aux:n #1
  { \exp_after:wN \int_value:w \dim_eval:w #1 \dim_eval_end: }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npx \dim_ratio_aux:w
  {
    \cs_set_nopar:Npn \exp_not:N \dim_ratio_aux:w ##1 \tl_to_str:n { pt }
      {##1}
  }
\dim_ratio_aux:w
```

This will go into the development version of `expl3` later today. (This works in `sp`, so the numbers will be quite large if given in `pt` but the code should be reliable.)

Comment: @Joseph: Thanks for your thorough explanation.

Comment: @Joseph: Great! But upload to CTAN will be deferred?

Comment: @Alexander: Unless it is urgent, then yes. We are currently doing some work to overhaul parts of `expl3`, and are wary of sending that to CTAN too close to the TeX Live freeze in case there are issues. However, if it's urgent I can arrange a release this month.

Comment: @Joseph: This would be very helpful, if you don't mind. I am writing a package for CTAN and maybe I could submit it before the TeX Live freeze. Do you know when the freeze will be?

Comment: @Alexander: OK, I'll move the code over and arrange a release.

Comment: @joseph: `\dim_ratio_aux:w` is defined to strip `pt` but not used? By the way, I'd use `\exp_args:Nno \cs_set_nopar:Npn {\dim_ratio_aux:w #1} {\tl_to_str:n {pt}} {#1}` for the def, but that's just taste.

Comment: @Bruno: Oops, a left-over from some testing